# Can I update mongodb documents using regular expressions i.e. $regex? I want to remove certain prefixes and suffixes from fields

Tags: regex, mongodb

Due to an error in data input all field values have extra quotes (even for numbers). There is probably not too much I can do with the data source (a TSV file with each value in quotes. I used mongoimport to import it.) so I thought of fixing this with updating in the db. if that doesn't work I will have to reupload after fixing the TSV file (messy).

either way it will be messy i guess. first pass - to remove quotes. second pass - to fix data types. this is my plan. also messy.

is there something the equivalent of the Perl regex `s/^""(.*)""$/$1/i` that I can use in updating a query result?

```
  _id  :  5d3585413a5ff3793f839e67
  user_id:  ""413799""
  individual_id:NaN
  first_name  : ""Doe""
  middle_name   :  """"
  last_name  :  ""John""
```

Comment: I think starting with a messy db and trying to fix it will be more expensive than cleaning the data with a program before import. Or, just skip the import and write an insert program that cleans the data. Use your regex program of choice.

Comment: Thanks Emma. that site is very helpful.

Comment: @DaveStSomeWhere - that does sound like a better plan. in bulk updates though it would be through files. was trying to reuse existing tools to do that.

Comment: My TSV (an export from a relational db) had every value in double quotes. Turns out ```mongoimport``` does not ignore these quotes - https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-61. For now I used ```MS Excel``` to Open (which handles the quotes fine) and do a Save As which removes these quotes but keeps the TSV format intact (somehow I couldn't achieve this with just text manipulation - regex on ```Notepad++```. it messed up columns.) The import now worked fine. But yes, this must be a one off solution.